# all my headphones work on one side on htc desire but they used to work fine

Tags: htc-desire, htc, headphone-jack

i have a HTC desire and i had 5 pairs of earphones that used to work fine...basically each time i bought new earphones for my htc they would work fine and then after about 4 months one side would stop working and it works a little if i move the cable at the input jack. i only used my earphones on my HTC.....is something wrong with my phone jack?? im tired of buying new earphones...i also take really good care of them because at first i thought i was breaking them..please help me!

Comment: If those headphones work properly everywhere else, then your phone's headphone jack is faulty.

Answer (score 2):

Your phone's headphone jack is failing.  When you buy new phones, the plug is a nominal dimension (3.5 mm is the standard, but the specification is surely much more precise than that).  After inserting and removing the plug a few hundred times, the tip and rings wear, reducing their size a tiny bit.  The same wear occurs on the spring-loaded contacts inside the jack.  After some number of cycles, it reaches the point where one of the contacts doesn't connect when the plug is fully inserted, but *something* connects on that conductor during insertion and removal.

In a new jack, there's plenty of overtravel in the contacts to cover this amount of wear, but if one of the spring tabs has gotten bent a bit (possibly by off-axis insertion of the plug at some point, or the headphone wire getting jerked out of the socket at an angle) it may make contact but have lost the overtravel that serves to take up wear.  The only real solution is to replace the jack -- which probably requires major work on the phone.  It might be possible, depending how the jack is made, to rebend the contact springs -- but that would require full disassembly of the phone and might not work, so it likely isn't worth paying someone to do.  Replacing the phone's motherboard may be the only solution, unless the phone jack is on a daughterboard.

Comment: Interesting. I always wondered why my earphones stops working in one side after being used for few months. Is this practical knowledge or have you read about this somewhere? Would you care to mention it in the latter case?

Comment: I've personally repaired this problem in devices much less compact than a cell phone.  It's only practical with "open" jacks, not in the ones that have a full enclosure (which is most of them, these days).

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty safe bet that something is going on with your headphone jack.  It could simply be defective or damaged but there is a strong possibility that it may simply need to be cleaned.  Pocket lint or other materials accumulating in your headphone jack could be the issue. This was a common issue I encountered when working with customers phones at Verizon and many times we would use compressed air to clean out debris from the jack, although occasionally we would have to actually insert a tool into the jack to clean it.  Debris shifting around inside the jack could also explain the intermittent nature of the issue.  Just be careful cleaning if you do find any debris and make sure you don't damage the jack or void your warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem solution is :the wire is disconnected from the chip where mic and volume control buttons are given..open that portion on the backside of chip there are four wires you can find the disconnected wire simply solder them. or go to any shop to solder them.